# How to enable images and documents upload in MediaWiki without login

Tags: dns, upload, mediawiki

I am working in project for documenting diffrent documentation in my company. For that purpose I have installed MediaWiki that will be avaliable only for domain users - not from outside company.

So I whant that no loggin is needed, so every user in domain could edit articles, upload documents, images. So fare everyone can edit text, but cannot upload documents and images if user is not logged in.

I have try in LocalSettings.php this:

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = true;
```

But after refresh server, still when try to upload file or image, it says, that I need to be logged in to upload.

What sould I more do, to enable upload without log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as mentioned in [Documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads#Upload_permissions)

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['upload'] = true;
```

This might also be useful to avoid problems in the future

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['reupload'] = true;
```

Comment: it enables upload, but when I am trying to save, I gen an error, that it fails to upload in stock (UploadStashNotLoggedInException): "No user is logged; files must be owned by users"

Comment: Ah I see, not sure what can be done about that sorry.

Comment: I didn't see whole result of solution that you wrote, because I had some random bootstrap skin to my mediawiki and I did not see, that below textarea (where I can write text) shows button (upload files) <= from here I can upload files because wggrouppermission.upload is set to true :)